# Convert a string containing a hexadecimal value starting with "0x" to an integer or long

Tags: c#, integer, hex

How can I convert a string value like "0x310530" to an integer value in C#?

I've tried *int.TryParse* (and even *int.TryParse* with *System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any*) but it does not work.

**UPDATE:**
It seems that Convert.ToInt64 or Convert.ToInt32 work without having to remove the leading "0x":

```
long hwnd = Convert.ToInt64("0x310530", 16);
```

The documentation of `Convert.ToInt64 Method (String, Int32)` says:

> "If fromBase is 16, you can prefix the number specified by the value
> parameter with "0x" or "0X"."

However, I would prefer a method like TryParse that does not raise exceptions.

Comment: good question, but -1 - Convert.ToInt32 does not work...

Comment: "Laeding" or "prefix" "0x" (not "trailing).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
int value = (int)new System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter().ConvertFromString("0x310530");
```

Comment: This works indeed, thanks. I would still prefer a method like TryParse that does not raise exceptions.

Comment: @David: Build a wrapper around it which catches the exception and behaves like TryParse. You could even try some method extension magic if you use C# 3.0 or later.

Comment: More on TypeConverter goodness [direct from SHanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TypeConvertersTheresNotEnoughTypeDescripterGetConverterInTheWorld.aspx)

Answer (score 18):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx):

> *NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier*
>
> Indicates that the numeric string represents a hexadecimal value. Valid hexadecimal values include the numeric digits 0-9 and the hexadecimal digits A-F and a-f. Strings that are parsed using this style **cannot be prefixed** with "0x" or "&h".

So you have to strip out the `0x` prefix first:

```
string s = "0x310530";
int result;

if (s != null && s.StartsWith("0x") && int.TryParse(s.Substring(2),
                                                    NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier,
                                                    null,
                                                    out result))
{
    // result == 3212592
}
```

Comment: Seems like a terrible name then because "0x" and "&H" are common hexadecimal specifiers, and yet they aren't "allowed". Weird.

Comment: can you please my related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61857579/converting-string-to-equivalent-hex-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Dai I think you have to read it as 'Allow the Hex-Specifier / allow that it is specifying a hex value'.

Answer (score 3):

[Direct from SHanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TypeConvertersTheresNotEnoughTypeDescripterGetConverterInTheWorld.aspx), as pointed by [Cristi Diaconescu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279892/convert-a-string-containing-a-hexadecimal-value-starting-with-0x-to-an-integer#comment28679868_4280019), but I've included the main source code:

```
public static T GetTfromString<T>(string mystring)
{
   var foo = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
   return (T)(foo.ConvertFromInvariantString(mystring));
}
```

The whole article deserves a closer look!

Comment: can you please my related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61857579/converting-string-to-equivalent-hex-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the leading 0x, you could use int.Parse

```
int a = int.Parse("1310530", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

Comment: Yes you do. Otherwise, it will parse the 0, and stop at the x.

Comment: AllowHexSpecifier does not work with strings like "0x310530", it's documented: "Strings parsed using this style are not permitted to be prefixed with "0x"."

Comment: @Oded: actually; yes, you do.

Comment: But that's a totally different number!

Answer (score 0):

Building further upon Caverna's answer I added a tryparse method so we can test if a conversion is valid to a certain type.

```
public static T GetTfromString<T>(string mystring)
{
    var foo = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    return (T)(foo.ConvertFromInvariantString(mystring));
}

public static bool TryGetTFromString<T>(string mystring, out T value)
{
    try
    {
        value = GetTfromString<T>(mystring);
        return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```