# How do I convert 0xFFFF to an int32 in c#

Tags: c#, hex

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Convert a string containing a hexadecimal value starting with “0x” to an integer or long in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279892/convert-a-string-containing-a-hexadecimal-value-starting-with-0x-to-an-integer)
>   [How to parse hex values into a uint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98559/how-to-parse-hex-values-into-a-uint)

I have a textbox that can have "0xFFFF" in it's Text property. I need to convert it to an int32.

How do I do that? I have tried:

```
Int32.Parse( MyTextBox.Text, NumberStyles.HexNumber )
```

and

```
Int32.Parse( MyTextBox.Text, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
```

and get the following error message:

"Input string was not in a correct format."

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

take off the 0x and just parse the actual hex number.