# C# Hex String into Hex int

Tags: c#, string, int, hex

**Can someone edit this to look better? Thanks!**

I'm trying to have a string that is a Hex value but it is set by a third party (Not The Code Itself) and set it back to an int but still be a Hex value. C# Will let you have an int that is equal to a Hex if you have the 0x in front.

Code:

```
string HexValue = "0x0FC";
int OtherValue = Convert.ToInt(HexValue);
```

When I try this I get: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: This question already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4280019/2850543

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a string containing a hexadecimal value starting with "0x" to an integer or long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279892/convert-a-string-containing-a-hexadecimal-value-starting-with-0x-to-an-integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert string into a int hex value by adding this `System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber`:

```
string HexValue = "0x0FC";
int OtherValue = int.Parse(HexValue.Substring(2),System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Had to take away my upvote because you didn't run the code. It doesn't work with `0x` on the front

Comment: Ooops, updated my answer. You're not allowed to pass string with leading "0x", so you should remove it thru substring.

Comment: @mindOfAi Ok that worked not instead of posting a new thing how would I do this?: string Value = "0.0F";  float NewValue = Value;

Comment: You can just do this:

string Value = "0.2F"; 
float NewValue = float.Parse(Value.TrimEnd('F'));