# C# Json converting hex literal string to int

Tags: c#, json, jsonconvert

A bit stuck, (confusing myself really, I think).

I am wanting to convert a value from a JSON string from it String representation of hex to an int.  I only need to get the value I will never need to write the other way.

For instance

```
{
   "name" : "someName",
   "id" : "b1"
}
```

I have a class created

```
public class Person
{
   public string name;
   [JsonConverter(typeof(myConverter))]
   public int id;
}
```

and my converter (I am not sure I understand this part correctly)

```
public class myConverter : JsonConverter
{
  //CanConvert Boiler Plate
  
  public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {

       string sValue = existingValue.ToString().ToUpper();
       int iValue = Convert.ToInt32(sValue);

       return iValue;
    }
```

I will of course add additional checks to validate data and what not, but I wanted to start with something to see how it worked.

So with the above example I would want my int to be 177

Any help, guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` takes a second parameter for the number base, pass 16.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert integer to hexadecimal and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139957/convert-integer-to-hexadecimal-and-back-again)

Comment: Ugh, I knew that. Let me try, While I may have known that at one point, I forgot in this case.

Comment: IMHO I would use `int.Parse(existingValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);`. The reason for this is because your hex values don't seem to be prefixed with `0x` and your current implementation could fail. On the other hand if they are prefixed, `Convert.ToInt32(existingValue, 16);` would suffice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Hex String into Hex int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917645/c-sharp-hex-string-into-hex-int)

Comment: Thanks all, I have the conversion figured out, I am now having an issue with the Json  portion.  I will figure that out though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `Newtonsoft.Json`? I notice your code wouldn't work on .NET `System.Text.Json` since:

- There is no public non-generic version of `JsonConverter`.
- It wouldn't work on `id` because it's not a property.

Here's the working code for `System.Text.Json`:

```cs
public class HexConverter : JsonConverter<int>
{

    public override int Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var value = reader.GetString();
        return Convert.ToInt32(value, 16);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, int value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The class has to contain properties to be deserialized:

```cs
public class Person
{

    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(HexConverter))]
    public int id { get; set; }

}
```

Usage:

```cs
const string json = @"{
   ""name"" : ""someName"",
   ""id"" : ""b1""
}";

var person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(json, new JsonSerializerOptions());

Console.WriteLine(person!.id);
// Result: 177
```

This case `Convert.ToInt32` works for me, but you can also use `int.Parse` as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft yes.

Answer (score 3):

Try following Command to Convert a Hex-Number to an int

```
var hex = "b1"
int intValue = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```